# Firebase delete method

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a json in Realtime firebase that look something like that :

```
{
  "-NMtZNTISnGhT-rdibeb": {
    "motorista": "Jose",
    "plate": "IZC2F45",
    "produto": "caroco",
    "transp": "VIDAL"
  },
  "-NN1zI2MHFtbi6G5qUvR": {
    "motorista": "ANTONIO",
    "plate": "AWJ-9353",
    "produto": "CAROCO",
    "transp": "GRANLIDER"
  }
}
```

I'm working with a python code that sould delete a select line from a `Treeview(Tkinter)` and also delete from this database. The method Delete is called from a `Button(tkinter)`. Actually he delete only the select line from Treeview, but don't delete from database.

```
def delete(self):        
    selected_item = self.tree.selection()
    if selected_item:
       
        id = self.tree.item(selected_item, "text")     
        url = self.base_url + id + '.json'
        response = requests.delete(url)
        print(url)
        print(response)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            self.tree.delete(selected_item)
            messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Linha deletada com sucesso!")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Erro", "Não foi possível deletar a linha!")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Erro", "Nenhum item selecionado para deletar!")
```

also, i made 2 prints to check what he gave me. and this is what i got from prints:

ttps://fila2-6bd6b-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/-NNh38XBrRen17bGWHga.json
<Response [200]>

already tried chatgpt, reddit. Already check the Rules from laboratory in firebase and he allowed to use Delete, get, update.

https://github.com/ChristopherMachad/truckQueueOnline/blob/main/Main.py

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, and the status code 200 in the response seems to indicate the the database also processed the request correctly. Are you sure the `id` that you're passing in is correct? I.e. the URL that you have in your question right now doesn't show any data when I access it, so there'd be nothing to delete when calling that.

Comment: i made another print for id. Just to check the id, and he return the correct id for the select line. I don't know why you aren't getting any data from this database, but when i work with another method like add, update or get the code works fine with this database.

Comment: Still unsoved....

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes, and now after 2 weeks it's working. this is how the function works :

```
def delete(self):
    selected_item = self.tree.selection()[0]
    base_url = "https://filachifrudos-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/pedido/"
    url = f'{base_url}{selected_item}.json'
    requests.delete(url)
    print(url)
    self.tree.delete(selected_item)
```

- The problem was that the url wasn't getting the right link.
  when i made a print to check what url gave me, the code return "link/pedido.json/ID.json". So i had to format that. Now the code return "link/pedido/id.json" and this way he delete from treeview and also the database.

tip for me: MORE ATTENTION IN PRINTS. THEY ALWAYS HAVE THE ASWER!!!